# How to append a string to all occurrences of another string in file

Tags: regex, string, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that would modify all occurrences of a certain string in a file.

I have a file with a bunch of text, in which urls occur. All urls are in the following format:`http://goo.gl/abc23` (that's goo.gl/, followed by 4 OR 5 alphanumeric characters).

What I'd like do is append a string to all urls. `http://goo.gl/abc23` would become `http://goo.gl/abc23?AString`, `http://goo.gl/JB007` would become `http://goo.gl/JB007?AString` and so on.

I've been trying this for the past 3 hours and got nowhere. I'm sure it's not very hard.

I've tried with sed (search and replace) and regex, but I don't know how to just **append** to a string, NOT replace it. I'm not very good with bash or regex.

Can anyone help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some kind of delimiter after the URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`, your methodology would be to "replace the current string with the current string plus another one." So, if you had some regex to match all of your URLs (since I don't want to write one on the fly):

```
sed 's/myregex/&?AString/g' myfile.txt
```

You'd have your entire regex in place of `myregex`. The `&` character puts the entire matched string on the right side, and the rest of the right-hand part of the substitution adds `?AString`. The `g` at the end tells `sed` to substitute all instances on a line, rather than just the first.

Comment: Awesome, it works. I didn't know about the &. I kept trying with $ and $1 and the like.

Comment: Now, is there a way to add a different string to each occurrence? Let's say I have a function `generatestring` that echos a different string each time. If I call it with `sed "s/http:\/\/goo.gl\/...../&?$(generatestring)/g"`, it (expectedly) writes the same string every time. Any ideas how I could write a different string after each time?

Comment: @user1199569 If the string isn't derived from the string you're appending to (i.e. a subset or something), I'm not sure how you would without having a bunch of `sed` commands. If that were the case, `perl` might be the way to go. That being said, poke around at it and if you can't figure it out, post a separate question to SO! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A perl way to do it, assuming URLs end with a space:

```
perl -pne 's#(http://\S+)#$1?AString#g' input_file
```

Comment: with perl, you don't need the capturing parentheses if you use `$&` instead of `$1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace the end of string (`$`):

```
sed 's/$/?AString/' input.txt
```